# Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync() and OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am using ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 to upload files in the following way:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    /* read the content */
    var contentTypeHeader = Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
    var contentLength = Request.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

    /* Here I get the exception if the file is > 60/70 MB */
    var filesProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    var fileContents = filesProvider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();
    var headers = fileContents.Headers;
    Stream fileStream = await fileContents.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    // ... code not related to this question
}
```

I have already setup the web.config as following, in order to accept files up to 1GB of data:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
```

And

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

But I still get this exception. The Exception has this structure:

```
An error occurred System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
↵   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
↵   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
↵   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
↵   at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

So, it looks to me like a .NET Exception and not something related to my code. But then, how can I use MultiPart to upload big files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the virtual directory ("~/uploads" directory as below example) where the image files are first uploaded are physically existance.

```
string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");

MyStreamProvider streamProvider = new MyStreamProvider(uploadPath);
```